Can we generate invoice for one time payment by passing paymentIntentd
I have below flow:

My system displays the following two products to the user, each priced at $10:


T-Shirt
Jeans

User can select products from the system. Suppose, the user selects 2 quantities of T-Shirts and 1 Jeans. According to calculation, the total amount is $30. However, we offer discounts to users for the first time based on our policy, so the final amount may be less than $30, like it may be $20.

When a user clicks on the "Pay Now" button, I am calling paymentIntents create api to charge a customer.

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          amount: amount,
          currency: 'usd',
          customer: customerId,
          payment_method: defaultPaymentMethod,
          confirm: true,
          return_url: process.env["WEBURL"],
        });


This code charges a customer and generates an email receipt. But, I want receipt to be more descriptive. I want to include line items to the receipt. How can I do that?

Note: I have also created products with price as $10 in the stripe as well.

I know that, invoice is one of the other way with the help of which I can generate line items.
But, I want final amount should be provided by our end instead of calculating from the stripe. How can I show line items with final amount from my end.


The way to do it is to use the Invoices API as suggested here https://docs.stripe.com/invoicing/integration?method=elements#accept-invoice-payment . Once the invoice is created you can use the underlying payment_intent to collect the payment in the front end
